# SQL adding two columns (datetime)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns that contains datetimes and i need two add them together somehow. I've tried using sum but that didnt work. Im using sqlserver 2008.

**Columns**

**loanPeriod** = the loanperiod of the item

**checkOutDate**= when the item was borrowed

And Im trying to achieve this
lastreturndate = (checkoutDate + loanperiod)

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: In what units is loanperiod, days?

Comment: @Tahbaza Days will actually be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select dateadd(month, loanperiod,  checkoutdate) as lastreturndate`

Answer (score 2):

Most databases have a DATEADD() or DATEDIFF() function or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, these are measured in days.  So, you can do something like this:

```
select dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, loanPeriod), checkoutDate)
```

It is odd to store the loan period as a datetime.  If so, the date is going to look like some date early in the 1900s (unless the period is very long).  The above converts it to days and then adds it to the check out date.

Comment: What do you suggest i store loanperiod as?

Comment: @Sebastian . . . It depends on what values it could be.  The first thing that comes to mind is number of days.  Alternatively, it could be a pair of a number and a unit. . . (2, 'years'), (14, 'months'), or whatever.

Comment: days is a lot better than a number and unit.  number and unit have no redeeming qualities.  I think the best bet though, is due date.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ok, Im a bit confused. Checkoutdate = the exact time of when someone borrows an item, i dont know if im suppose to use datetime or timestamp. And loan period is the amount of months that you can hold the item. Thanks in advance

Comment: EDIT:Loanperiod is measured in days.